# What is the complexity of set_intersection in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, set, time-complexity, set-intersection

What is the complexity of the following code?

```
set<int> S1, S2, ans;
set_intersection(S1.begin(), S1.end(), S2.begin(), S2.end(), inserter(ans, ans.begin()))
```

where `S1` and `S2` are some non_empty sets and `ans` is an empty set.

I know that inserting a sorted range into a set is linear; but is inserting using inserter linear too?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The inserter remembers where it last inserted each item and tries to insert the next item at the same place. This is O(1) if it's the right place.

Which means copying a sorted range to the inserter is linear overall, so you're good here.

Comment: I'm a bit confused: isn't O(1) constant instead of linear?

Comment: @AntonioPérez: It's constant per insertion; linear overall.